# Gentoo Linux global environments for root

Tags: linux, environment-variables, gentoo

I'm confused with setting variables in `/etc/env.d` directory. When I write `echo $PATH` from user - it's print me all variables that set it myself. But from root I see one... Where should I set variables for root?

Comment: Please recheck the [faq], this is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `ROOTPATH` instead of `PATH` in your /etc/env.d/* files.